# How to get SASS variables working in Ionic project?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I finally have a need for SASS vars so I am trying to get them to work for the first time, but they don't appear to be loading, or if they are being loaded they aren't being translated.

It's an Ionic v1 app, running with Ionic CLI v6.10.1

Here is my gulpfile.js (Gulp v4):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

var paths = {
  sass: ['./scss/**/*.scss']
};

gulp.task('default', ['sass']);

gulp.task('sass', function(done) {
  gulp.src('./scss/ionic.app.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .on('error', sass.logError)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .pipe(cleanCss({
      keepSpecialComments: 0
    }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.css' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/css/'))
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass'], function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
});
```

And in my projectRoot/scss/ionic.app.scss file I have:

```
$tabs-icon-size:                  25px !default;
$tabs-height:                     35px !default;
$eBlue:                     #192a67;
$eBlueRGB:                  25, 42, 103;
$eYellow:                   #f8d294;
$eYellowRGB:                248, 210, 148;
$eOrange:                   #f5aa07;
$eOrangeRGB:                245,168,7;

// The path for our ionicons font files, relative to the built CSS in www/css
$ionicons-font-path: "../lib/ionic/fonts" !default;

// Include all of Ionic
@import "www/lib/ionic/scss/ionic";
```

And to test my first scss variable, I added one to a class for a custom color:

```
.button-custom {
  background-color: $eBlue; 
}
```

But its not working.  Inspecting the element I see `button-custom` applied to the button I am trying to change, but the `background-color: $eBlue ;` is striked out.

At the beginning of the `ionic build android` output I see:
`[23:27:44] Invoking sass gulp task.`

After further reading on SASS vars in Ionic, I then added my custom variables to the `www/lib/ionic/scss/_variables.scss` file thinking I have my variables in the wrong location, but after I recompiled my app it still wasn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

Put all your variables into the `./scss/ionic.app.scss` file.

From CLI of project, run `gulp sass` - this copies a new file to `./css/ionic.app.css` with all your variables applied throughout the custom css file.

In HTML index.html - remove: `<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">`

And add: `<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">`